# How to Access DataTable Information Filled By a Module From a Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datatable, dataset, dataview

I have a DataSet named **BillMat.xsd**

[image: BillMat Dataset]

When my application loads, a module fills that dataset's DataTable [image: DataTable] with the correct information.

My question is ... How can I access that DataTable's already filled information from another form?

---

Here's how I tried to access it on one of my forms:

```
Dim View As New DataView
View.Table = BillMat.Tables("dtBillHeader")
```

But I get the following error:

[image: Non Shared]

If I create a new instance of my dataset and store it in a variable, I'll be able to get rid of this error message but it will also get rid of all my data in my dataset's datatables ... Is there a way to access a DataTable's information from another form?

Comment: You need to fix it so both forms are referencing the same `DataSet` or `DataTable` object.  If one is a "child" form of the other, such as a dialog, you can pass it from the parent to the child via a property.  Otherwise, ideally, the same data object would be injected into both forms by some third object which created both of the forms.  Short of all that, you could create a singleton or global variable, but please don't!

Comment: @StevenDoggart Right, I also figured I should fix my form so that I reference to the same place ... In my module, I made a read only property which returns the DataSet and I can access it from there ... Although, I'm not quite used to dealing with DataSets and DataTables, will this create major flaws in my program? Or is it an acceptable solution?

Comment: Without knowing all of the specifics, that sounds perfectly legitimate to me.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Cool. If you want to provide your first comment as an answer I'll gladly +1 and accept. My problem is solved now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix it so both forms are referencing the same `DataSet` or `DataTable` object. If one is a "child" form of the other, such as a dialog, you can pass it from the parent to the child via a property. Otherwise, ideally, the same data object would be injected into both forms by some third object which created both of the forms. Short of all that, you could create a singleton or global variable, but please don't!